# Binding Cursor data to a non-list layout

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm writing a screen that displays a row's worth of information from a DB.  Basically it's a Detail Fragment that represents information pertaining to one 'row' in a table.  I want to understand the best practice for binding data from a cursor (one unique row from a table) to a layout of textviews, checkboxes, etc.

Is AdapterView the ticket?

@JoeMalin suggested:

> Then write an adapter between a cursor and an array of text views.

Which boils down my question.  What's the right way to hook a series of text views to a cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do processing on some of the cursor data before you move it to the text views, then you're going beyond the adapter pattern, which assumes that "recasting" the form of a data structure to another data structure without any intermediate processing. The virtue of an adapter is that, for two data structures A and B linked by an adapter, it's assumed that B automatically changes whenever A changes.

Of course, you can redefine the idea of adapter to insert your own intermediate operation, such as converting dates, *or* you could make the conversion an aspect of the view that's displaying the data. I am guessing that the "processing" is really formatting, which you do for display purposes. That's an attribute of the text view, not the data; write something that extends text view and converts dates as needed. Then write an adapter between a cursor and an array of text views.

Comment: You're right, it's formatting, not processing.  For my ListViews, I do that formatting in bindView.  I see that I could also extend a TextView to be a "TimeView" that knows how to internally format a datetime.

My questions still comes down to your last suggestion: write an adapter between a cursor and an array of text views.  I don't know how to do that and would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented my own data adapter class that may be in the ball park.

```
public class NoteImageDataAdapter {

private final View mMainView;
private Cursor mCursor;
private ViewHolder holder;
private ContentObserver mContentObserver;

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView title;
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
}

public NoteImageDataAdapter(View mainView, Cursor c) {
    if (mainView == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("View mainView cannot be null");
    }

    if (c == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cursor c cannot be null");
    }
    mMainView = mainView;
    mCursor = c;

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    holder.text = (TextView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    holder.image = (ImageView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

    mContentObserver = new ImageNoteContentObserver(new Handler());
    mCursor.registerContentObserver(mContentObserver);
    bindView();
}

class ImageNoteContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public ImageNoteContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.d("NoteImageDataAdapter", "ImageNoteContentObserver.onChange( "
                + selfChange + ")");
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        mCursor.requery();
        bindView();
    }
}

public void bindView() {
    Log.d("NoteImageDataAdapter", "bindView");
    mCursor.moveToFirst();

    holder.text.setText(Note.getText(mCursor));
    holder.title.setText(Note.getTitle(mCursor));

    Uri imageUri = Note.getImageUri(mCursor);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        assignImage(holder.image, imageUri);
    } else {
        Drawable d = Note.getImageThumbnail(mCursor);
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(d);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private static final int MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 1024*512;

private void assignImage(ImageView imageView, Uri imageUri){
    if (imageView != null && imageUri != null){

        ContentResolver cr = imageView.getContext().getContentResolver();

        Display display = ((WindowManager) imageView.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = (int) (display.getWidth() * 0.9);
        int height = (int) (display.getHeight() * 0.9);

        int minSideLength = Math.min(height, width);

        Bitmap b = Util.makeBitmap(minSideLength, MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS, imageUri, cr, false);

        if (b == null){
            b = Util.makeBitmap(minSideLength, MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS/2, imageUri, cr, false);                
        }
        if (b != null){
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }   
    }   
}
```

}

### and in your activity

```
private NoteImageDataAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.note_image_view_layout);

    wireDataAdapter();       
}

private void wireDataAdapter() {
    final String[] COLUMNS = new String[] { 
            Note.Columns.TITLE,
            Note.Columns.TEXT,
            Note.Columns.IMAGE_URI, 
            Note.Columns.IMAGE_THUMBNAIL,
            Note.Columns._ID };

    // the uri for the note row
    Uri contentUri = getIntent().getData();
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(contentUri, COLUMNS, null, null, null);

    View mainLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.noteImageViewLayout);
    mAdapter = new NoteImageDataAdapter(mainLayout, cur);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the activity use:

```
Adpater adapter = new Adapter(Activity.this or context , Cursor);
setListAdapter(adapter) in case of List Activity;
```

Otherwise

```
listViewObj.setAdpater(adapter)
```

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;
 private Context activityContext;

 private ViewHolder holder;

 public ContactsAdapter(Context aContext,Cursor cursor) {
        super(mContext, cursor);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext); 
        activityContext = aContext;

    }  

 public static class ViewHolder{
     public TextView textView1;
     // View Group on Row inflate lyaout that need to be used
     public ImageView imageView;
   }

 @Override
 public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) { 
  holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

 }


 @Override
 public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
  final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_inflate_layout, parent, false);  

        holder = new ViewHolder();
     holder.textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TEXTVIEW1);
  // Other Id that need to be used and are available on item_inflate_layout
     holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.IMAGEVIEW);
     v.setTag(holder);     
  bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;  
 }
 }
```

Comment: How do you associate the adapter with its parent? i.e.: setListAdapter?

Comment: If you are now using ListActivity then Adpater adpater = new Adpater(context,Cursor); listView.setAdpater(adpater)

Comment: My question is for non-list activities.  I'm not displaying a list, I'm displaying the details from one item in a list.

Comment: Desired layout is a collection of textviews, each corresponding to column data from one row of a table.  Some of the data (like dates), need to be processed before setting into the textview.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. There are many examples binding a cursor containing multiple rows to a list view using an adapter. The actual question was how to bind a cursor containing a single item to a single view using an adapter. The `setAdapter` method only exists for views that extend/implement `AdapterView`. E.g., start an activity with cursor, adapter, and list view for the master list of items. Then select an item from that list to start a separate activity with cursor, adapter, and linear layout for that single item detail. How do you bind that single-item activity?

Comment: @Alex yes the question seems to be edited several times Feb 14 '12 at 19:55 , Feb 14 '12 at 19:55 with added description. With the result of this abrupt changes and modifications , final problem Query has been drastically changed as that from inquired in initial scope. Hope you got what I mean...!